# table greek alphabet for the whole sheet

Tags: alphabet

I want to create a table of the Greek alphabet, roughly as it is done in the following figure, so that the letters themselves are large and bold and the entire alphabet is on an A4 sheet.

[image]

Here's my attempt.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
                \begin{tabular}{ c c c c c}
        \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\alpha$ & \mathversion{bold}  \Huge $\beta$ & \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\gamma \; \Gamma$ & \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\delta \; \Delta$  & \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\epsilon \; \varepsilon E$\\ 
        Альфа & Бета & Гамма & Дельта & Эпсилон \\ 
         &  &  &  &  \\ 
        \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\zeta \; Z$ & \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\eta \; H$ & \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\theta \; \vartheta \; \Theta$ & \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\iota \; I$  & \mathversion{bold}  \Huge $\kappa \; K$\\ 
        Дзета & Эта & Тета & Йота & Каппа \\ 
         &  &  &  &  \\ 
        \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\lambda \; \Lambda$ & \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\mu \; M$ & \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\nu \; N$ & \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\xi \; \Xi$  & \mathversion{bold} \Huge $o \; O$ \\ 
        Лямбда & Мю & Ню & Кси & Омикрон \\     
         &  &  &  &  \\ 
        \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\pi \; \Pi$ & \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\rho \; \varrho P$ & \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\sigma \; \Sigma$ & \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\tau \; T$  & \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\upsilon \; \Upsilon$ \\ 
        Пи & Ро & Сигма & Тау & Ипсилон \\ 
        &  &  &  &  \\ 
        \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\phi \; \varphi \; \Phi$ & \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\chi \; X$ & \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\psi \; \Psi$ & \mathversion{bold} \Huge $\omega \; \Omega$  &  \\ 
        Фи & Хи & Пси & Омега &  \\ 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

I want to get the most easy-to-read version, written as much as possible in the full sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest three letters per line, so you can more easily fill the sheet.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx} % for scalebox

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\centering
\flushbottom
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 1fil}
\mathversion{bold}

\newcommand{\GR}[2]{%
  \makebox[0.33333\textwidth]{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
    \scalebox{3.5}{$#1$}\\#2
    \end{tabular}%
  }\ignorespaces
}

\GR{\alpha}{Альфа}
\GR{\beta}{Бета}
\GR{\gamma \, \Gamma}{Гамма}

\GR{\delta \, \Delta}{Дельта}
\GR{\epsilon \, \varepsilon E}{Эпсилон}
\GR{\zeta \, Z}{Дзета}

\GR{\eta \, H}{Эта}
\GR{\theta \, \vartheta \, \Theta}{Тета}
\GR{\iota \, I}{Йота}

\GR{\kappa \, K}{Каппа}
\GR{\lambda \, \Lambda}{Лямбда}
\GR{\mu \, M}{Мю}

\GR{\nu \, N}{Ню}
\GR{\xi \, \Xi}{Кси}
\GR{o \, O}{Омикрон}

\GR{\pi \, \Pi}{Пи}
\GR{\rho \, \varrho P}{Ро}
\GR{\sigma \, \Sigma}{Сигма}

\GR{\tau \, T}{Тау}
\GR{\upsilon \, \Upsilon}{Ипсилон}
\GR{\phi \, \varphi \, \Phi}{Фи}

\GR{\chi \, X}{Хи}
\GR{\psi \, \Psi}{Пси}
\GR{\omega \, \Omega}{Омега}

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some adjustments need to be done if you plan to include this in some document, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I wanted. I want to print this out on a sheet. I plan to use it separately. But I don't see any restrictions on use inside another document. As I understand it, everything works

Answer (score 2):

```latex
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=10pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec   = {*{5}{Q[c,m]}},
row{odd}  = {font=\boldmath},
row{odd}  = {cmd=\scalebox{5}},
row{even} = {cmd=\scalebox{3}},
row{odd}  = {abovesep+=27pt},
columns   = {colsep+=10pt}
}
$\alpha$                  & $\beta$             & $\gamma \, \Gamma$              & $\delta \, \Delta$ & $\epsilon \, \varepsilon E$ \\
Альфа                     & Бета                & Гамма                           & Дельта             & Эпсилон                     \\
$\zeta \, Z$              & $\eta \, H$         & $\theta \, \vartheta \, \Theta$ & $\iota \, I$       & $\kappa \, K$               \\
Дзета                     & Эта                 & Тета                            & Йота               & Каппа                       \\
$\lambda \, \Lambda$      & $\mu \, M$          & $\nu \, N$                      & $\xi \, \Xi$       & $o \, O$                    \\
Лямбда                    & Мю                  & Ню                              & Кси                & Омикрон                     \\
$\pi \, \Pi$              & $\rho \, \varrho P$ & $\sigma \, \Sigma$              & $\tau \, T$        & $\upsilon \, \Upsilon$      \\
Пи                        & Ро                  & Сигма                           & Тау                & Ипсилон                     \\
$\phi \, \varphi \, \Phi$ & $\chi \, X$         & $\psi \, \Psi$                  & $\omega \, \Omega$ &                             \\
Фи                        & Хи                  & Пси                             & Омега              &                             \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]